# Passing latitude and longitude dynamically to angular google maps inside a ng-For loop from an Array of objects

Tags: angular, google-maps

I'm trying to pass latitude and longitude values dynamically from an array of objects to a ng-For loop. 
I'm able to pass dynamic values to 'agm-marker' tag, but when I pass the same values to 'agm-map' tag it is throwing error in console as

```
  InvalidValueError: setCenter: not a LatLng or LatLngLiteral: in property 
  lat: not a number
```

html file

```
    <div *ngFor="let item of restaurants">
      <mat-card style="margin:7px" class="example-card">
      <mat-card-content>
        Average cost for two : ₹ {{ item.restaurant.average_cost_for_two}} 
     <br />
        Location <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>:
        {{ item.restaurant.location.locality_verbose }} <br />
        Average user rating :
        {{ item.restaurant.user_rating.aggregate_rating }} out of 5 <br />
        <agm-map [latitude]="item.restaurant.location.latitude" 
         [longitude]="item.restaurant.location.longitude">
          <agm-marker [latitude]="item.restaurant.location.latitude" 
            [longitude]="item.restaurant.location.longitude"></agm-marker>
        </agm-map>
      </mat-card-content>
    </mat-card>
    </div>
```

component.ts file

```
  lat: number = 51.678418;
  lng: number = 7.809007;
  Title: any;
  restaurants: RestaurantSingle[];
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private service: 
   ZomatoService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
     this.route.params.forEach((params: Params) => {
      this.Title = params["id"];
   });
   console.log(this.route.snapshot.params["id"]);
  this.service.getRestaurant(this.Title).subscribe(
    data => {
    this.restaurants = data.restaurants;
    console.log(data);
    console.log(data.restaurants[0].restaurant.location.latitude)
    this.showRestaurants = true;
   },
   err => {
    console.log(err);
   });
  }
```

But when I replace with below code it's working fine.

```
      <agm-map [latitude]="12.2223" 
         [longitude]="55.644">
          <agm-marker [latitude]="item.restaurant.location.latitude" 
            [longitude]="item.restaurant.location.longitude"></agm-marker>
        </agm-map>
```

The response from Api for latitude and longitude are of number type.

Api response in console;

```
 restaurant:
 R: {res_id: 18784250}
 apikey: ""
 average_cost_for_two: 1200
  has_online_delivery: 0
  has_table_booking: 1
  id: "18784250"
  include_bogo_offers: true

 location:
 address: "Survey 263, Hissa 2, Hinjewadi Marunji Road, Near Laxmi Chowk, 
 Hinjawadi, Pune"
 city: "Pune"
 city_id: 5
 country_id: 1
 latitude: "18.5974587298"
 locality: "Hinjawadi"
 locality_verbose: "Hinjawadi, Pune"
 longitude: "73.7344924361"
 zipcode: ""
 medio_provider: 1 
 mezzo_provider: "OTHER"
 name: "Universal Barbeque"
 opentable_support: 0
```

Comment: Can you add sample response

Comment: added the shortened version of response from API @Ininiv

Comment: latitude&longitutde values are string "", convert it `latitude: parseFloat("18.5974587298"); longitude: parseFloat( "73.7344924361)"`

Comment: But I'm passing the data dynamically like [latitude]=parseFloat("item.restuarant.location.latitude")  in .html so it won't work. :(

Comment: Change it in the .ts file and bind in the HTML

Comment: how can it be done when I have multiple values like 30 or so.